# CsvHelper - can't match class object names to csv header names because of parentheses

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Using CsvHelper in Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Core 2.2.

The header names of my csv file contain parentheses in the names.  I don't have any control over the contents of this source csv file.

Per the getting started documentation at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started if your class property names match the csv file header names, we can read the file without any configuration.  But parentheses can't be used in class property names in C#.

Is there a way around this so I can make the my class property names match the header names including parentheses?  If not, how can I direct Csvhelper to handle this correctly?  The documentation only refers to adjusting the names for lowercase vs uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started#reading-a-csv-file):

> Using the configuration `PrepareHeaderForMatch`, we're able to change
>   how the header matching is done against the property name. Both the
>   header and the property name are ran through the `PrepareHeaderForMatch`
>   function. When the reader needs to find the property to set for the
>   header, they will now match. **You can use this function to do other
>   things such as remove whitespace or other characters.**

So (if only need to remove the parenthesis to match, otherwise, do your own logic):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{    
    csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => 
        header.Replace("(","").Replace(")","");
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}
```